# QTreeView disable selection on some rows

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I Have a `JSON` model, and I populate it with `QTreeView`:

```
*-group1
| |  
| *-item1     value1
| |
| *-item2     value2
|
*-group2
  |
  *-item4     value3
```

Now I want to disable selection for `groups`, so that user can select only rows with `items`. And I want to achive it without modification of model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proxy model such as [QIdentityProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qidentityproxymodel.html) and reimplement [QAbstractItemModel::flags()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags), removing the [Qt::ItemIsSelectable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) flag for the group items:

```
Qt::ItemFlags DisableGroupProxyModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const {
   const auto flags = QIdentityProxyModel::flags(index);
   if (index is group) {
       return flags & ~Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
   }

   return flags;
}
```

Then set the original (unmodified) model as source model of this proxy model and the proxy model instance as the tree view’s model:

```
DisableGroupProxyModel* proxy = new DisableGroupProxyModel(this);
proxy->setSourceModel(originalModel);
treeView->setModel(proxy);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `QItemSelectionModel`. You can get selection model with

```
treeView->selectionModel();
```

Then connect to model's signal

```
void currentRowChanged(const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous)
```

and inside the connected slot check if new index is group or not and if group just select `previous` model index.